# How to disable anchor tags in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I created a custom directive like this and it seems to work on all of the button elements in my project but not the anchor tags. The anchor tags have href as well as ng-click property that need to be disabled.

```
common.directive('permissionDir', ['permissionService', function(service) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
//      console.log(attrs.permissionDir);
        service.checkPermission(attrs.permissionDir).then(function(data) {

            element[0].disabled = !data;
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
  }]);
```

Based off of other posts I've read here it seems that anchor tags don't have a disabled property which is why it has no effect on the anchor tags.

I've tried adding something like this within the previous directive but it had no effect either.

```
        element.on('click', function(event) {
            if (attrs.disabled) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent link click from going through
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: a[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }

Comment: Could you please elaborate?